# Why does Xcode let me compile this custom iterator code?

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11

I'm learning custom iterators and I wrote this toy example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

bool IsOdd (int i) {
  return ((i%2)==1);
}

class MyIterator : std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, int>
{
  int *p;
public:
  MyIterator(int* x) :p(x) {}
  MyIterator(const MyIterator& mit) : p(mit.p) {}
  MyIterator& operator++() {++p;return *this;}
  MyIterator operator++(int) {MyIterator tmp(*this); operator++(); return tmp;}
  bool operator==(const MyIterator& rhs) {return p==rhs.p;}
  bool operator!=(const MyIterator& rhs) {return p!=rhs.p;}
  int& operator*() {return *p;}
};


int main () {
  int numbers[]={2,3,4,5,6};
  MyIterator from(numbers);
  MyIterator until(numbers+5);

  MyIterator ii = std::find_if(from, until, IsOdd);
  std::cout << "The first odd value is " << *ii << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

On my Apple computer, I can compile this code with clang++, which has version "Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)". But when I try and compile the code on my Ubuntu 14.04, I get this error:

```
In file included from iterators.cpp:5:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../../include/c++/5.3.0/algorithm:62:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../../include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_algo.h:162:10: error: no matching function for call to '__iterator_category'
                       std::__iterator_category(__first));
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../../include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_algo.h:3790:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__find_if<MyIterator, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<const int> >' requested here
      return std::__find_if(__first, __last,
                  ^
iterators.cpp:37:24: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::find<MyIterator, int>' requested here
  MyIterator ii = std::find(from, until, 31);
                       ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../../include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:204:5: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure
      [with _Iter = MyIterator]: no type named 'iterator_category' in 'std::iterator_traits<MyIterator>'
    __iterator_category(const _Iter&)
    ^
1 error generated.
```

My clang++ version on Ubuntu is "Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_34/final) (based on LLVM 3.4)" In both cases I'm compiling with "-std=c++11" flag.

I understand that I can get the code to compile by inheriting std::iterator publicly, but my questions are:

1. Is clang++ on Ubuntu correct in giving an error, or is Apple's clang++ not reporting an error when it should have?
2. When writing a custom iterator, is it better to just inherit std::iterator publicly all the time?

Comment: If you know the issue, why would you inherit privately? You're not using any of the provided typedefs yourself...

Comment: Formally, your program exhibits undefined behavior because `MyIterator` does not satisfy iterator requirements (for failure to provide certain public typedefs it's expected to provide). "Appears to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior; "fails to compile" is another.

Comment: I wasn't sure if inheriting publicly was the proper way to make the error go away, but I'll just do that then. Thanks for the help!